# How to limit access to an activity for some users only using Parse.com on android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm creating an app where I store on a parse.com database the GPS coordinates of stores. I'm also able to see markers on a map corresponding to these stores.

I'd like to be able to give access to some of my friends to the activity that allows us to add new stores. The regular user would only be able to see them on a map and not add them. Should I only start the intent if the current user is included in a list ?

Is there a better solution using Parse.com ACL ?

Arnaud

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have user login and you don't want to overcomplicate things I see 2 solutions:

1. Build a specific app versions for your friends which will include activities for adding stores.

   or
2. Hardcode device ids of your friends who should be able to add stores and using TelephonyManager check if it's the right device.

More flexible solution is to keep table with device ids in Parse.com and check them when app is launched for the first time. This will give you ability to add admins without releasing a new version on the market.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what **build flavours** are for, see [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants) for further details.

The approach is to extract feature-specific code into different flavours, and then assemble different versions of your app. This could be as simple as a different property configuration (allow_adding_stores) or as sophisticated as a specific activity.

Another typical usecase would be to build a separate debug version of you app (e.g. connecting to different servers or writing specific log statements).